# AngularJS: ngRoute causing too many redirects error?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, ngroute

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        ... {{ title }} ...
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/register" ng-hide="authenticated">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/login" ng-click="login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        ...
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ellipses to shorten the html. MainController just sets $scope.title = "My App"

In my angular module, I use ngRoute and implement routing as such:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider 
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    })
    .when('/login',
    {
        controller: 'AuthenticationController',
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .when('/register',
    {
        controller: 'AuthenticationController',
        templateUrl: 'register.html' 
    });
});
```

My AuthenticationController just defines the login and register functions to make post calls to the server, but I am not making those calls since I am not clicking login or register.

Everything works smoothly in terms of swapping out ng-view for the appropriate view, but when I open the console, every time I switch the view, I get a "localhost:3000/login" too many redirects. I find it odd because regardless if I click register, login, logout, it always says "localhost:3000/login" too many redirects. This is within the context of an express framework, but I don't think it is an error on my server side because it's doesn't appear to be hitting my app.use('/',index) router in express. Is this normal?

EDIT: Here is my index router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res,next)
    {
        return res.render('index', { title: 'SERVER TITLE' });
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

In app.js:

```
app.use('/', index); 
app.use('/auth', authenticate); 

app.all('*',function(req,res,next)
{
  if(req.isAuthenticated())
  {
    return next();
  }
  else
  {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Comment: Try the same thing with HTML5Mode turned off for $locationProvider. `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)`

Comment: Oh, I see it's already off. Hm. If you're error is referencing `localhost:3000/login` that would be coming from your server since you're linking to a hashroute. Share your server side code to debug further?

Comment: @dboskovic I've added my server side code... Now that you've narrowed it down to the server, the app.all call seems awfully suspicious. But why are my hash filepaths from clicking the navbar menu items making server requests?

Comment: I'm pretty confident they're starting out as requests for your templates. (see templateUrl) and getting redirected to login. Maybe make sure you're defining / caching your templates properly in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my client side routing was faulty, so my requests ended up to the server, which ended up in multiple redirects.